# Parse XML data to 2D array in python

Tags: python, xml, multidimensional-array, xml.etree

I am fairly new to python and am just learning about XML files and 2D arrays. I'm trying to take data from an xml file and import it into a 2D string array in python.
I created the following xml file from a table:

```
<members>

    <member>
        <FirstName>Jarrod</FirstName>
        <LastName>Weiss</LastName>
        <DOB>12-08-1991</DOB>
        <DateJoined>4-05-2017</DateJoined>
        <Paid>TRUE</Paid>
    </member>

    <member>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <DOB>22-09-1980</DOB>
        <DateJoined>1-03-2016</DateJoined>
        <Paid>TRUE</Paid>
    </member>

</members>
```

I've been trying using Elementree with no luck. This will access the last entry in the xml file but not the others.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse('members.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
for x in myroot.findall('member'):
    FirstName = x.find('FirstName').text
    LastName = x.find('LastName').text
    DOB = x.find('DOB').text
    DateJoined = x.find('DateJoined').text
    Paid = x.find('Paid').text
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The very code you've posted, without any modifications (except for addng `print(FirstName, LastName, DOB, DateJoined, Paid)` at the end of the loop), accesses both member entries in your xm (btw, you your closing tag in the xml is wrong, `</members>`). Post an actually reproducible example.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give an example of the 2D array you're trying to generate from the above XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse('members.xml')   # to parse file

print(mytree.tag)   # to get root tag
children = list(mytree)  # to get children element
```

Here is a simple for loop to print content, contruct 2D array, and a list of dictionary (this is my preferred):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse('members.xml')   # to parse file

print(mytree.tag)   # to get root tag
children = list(mytree)  # to get children element

arr = []                                 # 2D array
dic = []                                 # list of dict
for e in list(mytree):
    print(e.tag)                         # prints "member"
    ch = list(e)                         # get its children
    element = []
    elementdict = {}
    for ee in ch:
        print("\t", ee.tag, ":", ee.text) 
        element.append(ee.text)          # add text to arr[i]
        elementdict[ee.tag] = ee.text    # add text to dictionnary
    arr.append(element)        
    dic.append(elementdict)

print(arr)                ## print 2D array
print(dic)                ## print list of dictionaries
```

#### Output:

```
member
     FirstName : Jarrod
     LastName : Weiss
     DOB : 12-08-1991
     DateJoined : 4-05-2017
     Paid : TRUE
member
     FirstName : John
     LastName : Smith
     DOB : 22-09-1980
     DateJoined : 1-03-2016
     Paid : TRUE

## print(arr)
[['Jarrod', 'Weiss', '12-08-1991', '4-05-2017', 'TRUE'], ['John', 'Smith', '22-09-1980', '1-03-2016', 'TRUE']]

## print(dic)
[{'FirstName': 'Jarrod', 'LastName': 'Weiss', 'DOB': '12-08-1991', 'DateJoined': '4-05-2017', 'Paid': 'TRUE'}, {'FirstName': 'John', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'DOB': '22-09-1980', 'DateJoined': '1-03-2016', 'Paid': 'TRUE'}]
```